# How to make a responsive css grid with margins using auto-fit?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I don't NEED to use auto-fit. I just want the code to work.

I want a left margin of 89px, a right margin of 89px, and two items in the middle. So I originally had something like this:

```
.container3 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 89px 1fr 1fr 89px);
}
```

The above works, but is not responsive. I need these to break into separate rows when the screen goes smaller. This is the best I can come up with and it doesn't work...

```
.container3 {
  height: 800px;
  /* background-color: pink; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(
    auto-fit,
    89px minmax(300px, 1fr) minmax(300px, 1fr) 89px
  );
```

Comment: I'm not clear why you have the two margins as grid items rather than as actual margins on the container element. Could you include a simple snippet (ie including the HTML) so we can see the structure.

Comment: sounds to me that you dont want actual amrgins but padding left and right.

Comment: *I want a left margin of 89px, a right margin of 89px* --> then use margin, don't over-complicate it

Answer (score -1):

If you want them to break into separate rows, you can make use of grid breakpoints.[Bootstrap Grid options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#grid-options)

You can try something like this:

```
<div class="container3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">First row in xs screen / left column in medium and higher devices</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">Second row in xs screen / middle column in medium and higher devices</div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">Last row in xs screen / Right column in medium and higher devices</div>
    </div>
</div>
```